# Azure Data Factory copy activity timestamps unnecessary converting

Tags: azure-data-factory

I copy data from PostgreSQL table to a parquet file. The source is: SELECT * FROM <table_name>, the sink is path to ADLS (Azure data lake gen2). Copying is in a loop for many tables. The copying itself works but all timestamps have converted in the target parquet file.
For example in the source table I have: "2024-03-14 20:11:14.974813+00" - note that it is UTC time zone, in the target parquet I have: "2024-03-14T13:11:14.974Z", the difference is -7h.
It seems like timezone shift between UTC and eastUS region where the Data Factory instance is deployed.
The converting looks like a bug because both source and target timestamps are in UTC.

I know that casting the timestamps to string on the source side can help but I use "SELECT * FROM " with dynamically changed table name so I don't have control on any single column and type of it. I cannot apply such casting.

Any idea how to disable the unnecessary converting in ADF copy activity or any workaround?

### UPDATE

After some research I found this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/395981/self-hosted-integration-runtime-and-incorrect-date

It tells that the timestamp converting is on Self-hosted Integration Runtime side. I use the SHIR for ingestion from PostgreSQL.
Following the post I changed timezone on the machine where the SHIR is deployed to UTC and this took effect!
After the change the timestamp in the target parquet file is correct.
But this is only a workaround. In my distributed environment with many source systems enforcing timezone for all systems is problematic.

My first request is still valid: is there a way to disable timestamp converting in copy activity?

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue but its working fine form me you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/eV4Vusz.png) It might be some, but which is resolved now can you please check now? also check the parquet schema doesn't have any particular time zone

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue but its working fine form me you can see in below image there is no difference in time.

[image]

**A parquet file converts datetimes to UTC and saves them without timezone in the data fields. The parquet file does, however, store the timezone in its schema.**

- So, check the parquet schema of your file it might has different timezone.
- When a mapping is run to read from or write to fields of the Date and Timestamp data types in the Parquet file formats, the time zone defaults to the host machine time zone.

Comment: "@Pratik Lad" appreciation, you spent your time trying to replicate the issue.
In the parquet schema, there is no time zone:
  "Schema": [
    {
      "Field_id": 0,
      "Name": "timestamp",
      "Type": "INT96",
      "Type_length": 0,
      "LogicalType": null,
      "Scale": 0,
      "Precision": 0,
      "Repetition_type": "OPTIONAL"
    }
The issue doesn't exist when copying from Azure Database for PostgreSQL to parquet. It exists only when the Postgres instance is deployed in different timezone and used Self-hosted Integration Runtime. Cannot accept your answer